# Как перевести экспоненциальною запись в обычную?

Tags: javascript

Написал простенький скрипт который вычисляет долг моего друга .
Сумма выходит слишком огромной и записывается в экспоненциальную запись , а нужно в обычной что бы было по красоте.

Вопрос:
Как перевести экспоненциальную запись в обычную ?

```
let numbers = document.querySelector('h2')
let now = new Date()
let old = new Date('2021-06-1')
let days = Math.round((now.getTime() - old.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24))

function Debt(day){
    return 0.01*2**day
}

numbers.innerText=Debt(days) //1.5474250491067254e+24
```

Comment: Вот это должок..

Comment: Влад, не могли бы немного подробнее описать логику высчитывания долга?

Comment: @ИванИпатов, долг растёт экспоненциально 0.01*2**day , где 0.01 - начальная сумма долга , 2- (1 + процент за день, то есть 100% в день)